# Limiting text in visible typing area

Tags: javascript, jquery

In general user can type more in the text field. To limit character is time consuming process as it needs to check how many character can be typed in the input field. 
So I was trying in following way.

```
$.fn.textWidth = function(text, font) {
    if (!$.fn.textWidth.fakeEl) $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl = $('<span>').hide().appendTo(document.body);
    $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.text(text || this.val() || this.text()).css('font', font || this.css('font'));
    return $.fn.textWidth.fakeEl.width();
};

$('input').keyup(function(){
if($(this).innerWidth()< $(this).textWidth())
    {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,$(this).val().length-1));
    }

});
```

In console I am getting following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: textWidth is not defined
```

Would you suggest me what I should do?

Comment: you're sure it's not the `$(this).innerwidth()` that is the problem, as there is no such method in jQuery, it's `innerWidth()` (capital W)

Comment: Thanks now working well what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `maxlength` property in HTML to set the maximum length of the value in characters, no need for javascript here:

```
<input type="text" name="foo" maxlength="20" />
```